# Connecting to the MQ Server using CCDT

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to the `MQ` using the information present in the `CCDT` file. I can currently connect to the `MQ` using all the details, and get and put messages from and to the queue.

After extensive googling, I've been unable to find any sample code which allows me to connect using the `CCDT` file.

One of my colleagues forwarded me his `JMS` connection code, but I've been unable to port it to `C#`.

The `JAVA` code is as follows -

```
public class MQTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MQQueueManager queueManager = null;
    URL ccdtFileUrl = null;
    MQMessage mqMessage = null;
    //MQPutMessageOptions myPMO = null
    try {
     String QM =    "IB9QMGR";
     String QUEUE1 = "TEST";

     System.out.println("Starting MQClient Put Program: ");
     ccdtFileUrl = new URL("file:///D:/AMQCLCHL.TAB") ;
     ccdtFileUrl.openConnection();
     queueManager = new MQQueueManager("SDCQMGR.T1", ccdtFileUrl);

     System.out.println("Connected to QMGR ");
     int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
     MQQueue InQueue = queueManager.accessQueue(QUEUE1,openOptions,null,null,null);
     MQMessage inMessage = new MQMessage();
     inMessage.writeString("###Testing####");
     InQueue.put(inMessage);
     System.out.println("Message Id is :" + inMessage.messageId);
     System.out.println(inMessage.toString());
     InQueue.close();
     queueManager.disconnect() ;
 }
 catch(MQException ex){
     System.out.println("MQ Error - Reason code :" + ex.reasonCode);
 }
 catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error : " + e);
 }
}
}
```

Instead of `URL`, I used the `URI` (in C#) to set file location. (This may be wrongly used. Not sure what else to use though.)

```
Uri ccdtFileUrl = new Uri("file:///D:/AMQCLCHL.TAB") ;
```

but I can't use `openConnection()` on a URI. Also,

`queueManager = new MQQueueManager("SDCQMGR.T1",ccdtFileUrl);`
 gives an argument overload exception. As URI is not supported in C#.

I've tried looking up samples but I've found some JMS samples and thats it. Looking for some sample code to connect in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set `MQCHLLIB` and `MQCHLTAB` environment variables to use CCDT. You can set these two variables either from command prompt,app.config or code in the application itself.

Following example demonstrates usage of `CCDT`:

```
        MQQueueManager qm = null;
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLLIB", "C:\\ProgramData\\IBM\\MQ\\qmgrs\\QM1\\@ipcc");
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLTAB", "AMQCLCHL.TAB");

        try
        {
            **Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
            props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
            qm = new MQQueueManager("QM1",props);**
            MQQueue queue1 = qm.AccessQueue("SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE", MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
            msg.WriteUTF("Hello this message is from .net client");
            queue1.Put(msg);
            queue1.Close();
            qm.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Just some clarification. `QM1` is my Queue Manager Name.

Also, while setting `AMQCLCHL.TAB`, how should I specify where mine is? Its at `D:/AMQCLCHL.TAB` (on HDD) or `\TAB\AMQCLCHL.TAB` (in my project, imported).

Comment: Okay. Format please? just `"D:/AMQCLCHL.TAB"` ?

Comment: See the sample code above. It's setting the path(MQCHLLIB) and file name(MQCHLTAB) separately.

Comment: It's not the problem with path format. Check if the queue manager name specified in CCDT file is same as the one you are specifying application.

Comment: Sorry for being such a dumbass. This is my current code to set the variables.

                    `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLLIB", "D:/");`
                    `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLTAB", "AMQCLCHL.TAB");`

And I'm still getting the same error. Queue Manager name is correct.

Comment: See update code. I have added MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY property. This works for me. Try it